# how to set 2 layout on 1 drawer layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have one `drawer layout` contains one `fragment` like below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray_light_background_fragment" />

    <!-- Drawer view -->
     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="ui.fragment.drawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer_in_company_feed" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I follow this https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html and can show `drawer layout`. But my `drawer layout` has just **one** `view (layout)`

I would like drawer layout can show **2 (or many)** `views (layouts)` **at many the different contexts**. All `views (layouts)`is left side.

Example: At `Activity` **A**: drawer layout show `view (layout)` **A**. 
         At `Activity` **B**: drawer layout show `view (layout)` **B**.

Someone can help me. I look forward to your advice. Thanks you!

Comment: Set The draweview layout_width="300dp" and your main contentview layout_width="match_parent: try this

Comment: No, you did not understand. Please read again question.